# Silverlight convert datePicker to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, silverlight-4.0, datepicker

can someone tell me how to conver DatePicker value to DateTime value...

I have this variables:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DatePicker rd = rd_datePicker;
```

I would like to get difference in days betwen this two dates, can you help me with this too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`DatePicker.SelectedDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)?

Once you've got the two `DateTime` values (you may want to use `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now`) you can subtract one from the other to get a `TimeSpan`, and then use [`TimeSpan.TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) to find out the number of days in the period.

(As `DateTime` is effectively a "local" representation, you don't need to worry about time zones or variable day lengths in this particular case. Date and time arithmetic in general is [rather tricky](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx)...)

Answer (score -1):

```
 DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
 DateTime dt=new DateTime();
 dp.Text = dt.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: To [reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16074016): if the answer is bad but is an answer (like this is), don't recommend deletion: downvote! See, for example, "[You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007)" and "[When an answer answers the wrong question, is it Not An Answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185162/284827)". This is an answer. You may not agree with it, but it is an attempt to answer the question.